# Appium does not show webview context, it only showing native app context. How to get webview context?

Tags: java, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I'm trying to get the available application context and want to switch to the webview context but appium getting only Navive App.

Also application is WebView enabled.

- Appium version: 1.10.1
- ChromeDriver version: 2.44
- Desktop OS/version: Windows 10
- Node.js version: 10.14.2
- Package manager:Npm
- Mobile platform/version: Android/8.1.0
- Real device or emulator/simulator:google pixel 2 emulator
- Appium CLI or Appium.app|exe:Tried with both

  ```
      public void webView() {
             try {
                  Set<String> context = driver.getContextHandles();

                  for(String cont: context) {
                      System.out.println("Available Context : " + cont);
                      if(cont.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
                         driver.context(cont);
                         System.out.println("current context :"+cont);
                      } else {
                         System.out.println("Opps");
                      }
                  }
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
             }
      }
  ```

I expect the output as Native App and WebView of application will be get but the actual output is only getting Native App.

Comment: Can you post adb logcat logs?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/gohilniks/cc688f55fd495b94f34fefaa02f34353 Here is log file

Comment: Can you post the Desired Capabilites that you are setting? Also, how are you initializing the driver

Comment: https://gist.github.com/gohilniks/e2ab818b68266cb99cfca305e250745b Here is link for the code sample

Answer (score 0):

Please ask your dev to set  setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled to true. Refer following link 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

In IOS

Able to change context by safari.

but don't change context from webview of native app installed device